# How do I export a content type, views as a single module

Tags: console

I've a view, content type, field collection, flexslider to satisfy a single user case. May I know how to export all these three as a single module.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some Drupal Console export commands for this:

- [config:export:content:type](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/config-export-content-type.html)
- [config:export:view](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/config-export-view.html)

You could use the `--module` option to specificy which module to export.

It's easier to use the [Features module](https://drupal.org/project/features) though. From the project page:

> A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken
>   together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building
>   components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in
>   a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal
>   module except that it contains additional information in its info file
>   so that configuration can be checked, updated, or reverted
>   programmatically.
>
> Examples of features might be:
>
> - A blog
> - A pressroom
> - An image gallery

Comment: There is no way to export it using console?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information.

Answer (score 2):

Install and configure [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module.

> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building
>   components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in
>   a single feature module.

To export using terminal use ***Drush***.

Drush commands for features : https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/features/features-add/

Comment: There is no way to export it using console?

Comment: Drupal Console != Drush. But I agree, using features + drush is easier than using DC.

Comment: @WimMostrey I guess FazeelaAbuZohra asking about terminal.